# Liferay jsonws api: what is the staging url?

Tags: api, content-management-system, liferay

When a site has live content, it is possible to get the articles you posted using `/api/jsonws/invoke` URL and passing on a body with:

```
cmd:{"articles = /journal.journalarticle/get-articles": {"groupId": <gId>, "folderId": 0}}
p_auth: <p_auth>
```

But when the content is on staging mode, the same API returns a empty list. 
Yet there's a proper Web Content manager for the staging content... That means that there should be an API for that.

Does anyone know the URL for the staging content API, or how can I get this data using a different cmd?

(if possible, with no use of additional servlets/java development)

Comment: The api is the same, just the groupId differs. I'm writing this as a comment as I'm not on my computer and can't look up how to get the matching groupId, but it might help you find it yourself

Comment: I'm fetching the groups using the command {"$site = /group/get-user-sites-groups": {}}, but the results only show groups for Live sites. Any suggestions?